# How to allow <input type=“file”> to accept only image files for image upload

Tags: android, html

I am trying to show only those files whose extensions are jpg,png or jpeg . 
my html of form is this

```
 <input data-max-size="246k" accept="image/*" class="hidden" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="entry[paperclip_infos_attributes][new_paperclip_infos][picture]" id="entry_paperclip_infos_attributes_new_paperclip_infos_picture" />
```

it is working fine which i want but in android phone it asking for some more options for image upload like kingsoft office and wps office.

There is no issue in iphone. 
[image]
how can i control this options..??